# Android: how to use custom IME without intermediate EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime, spannablestringbuilder

I followed this tutorial to create a custom IME and am pretty happy with the result: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

However, when I click on an EditText to start typing, my keyboard is opened beneath some kind of new text entry popup (See images). I want the user to be able to type in monospace font, so I want to either:

1. Remove this pop up and type directly into my application OR
2. Style the text in this popup so its monospace.

Can anyone help or at least tell me what the term for this popup is, so I can Google it? :S

Images:

[Clicking in my text field results in this screen appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBL8Y.png)

Comment: There is no popup in the image that you linked to, AFAICT.

Comment: Aww fudge -_- I had two pics, it wouldn't let me link them both so I removed one.. the wrong one..

Comment: That's the standard look for an `EditText` in landscape. You can see this by using most Android apps on most Android devices in landscape. The `EditText` can request that this not be done via `flagNoFullscreen` on `android:imeOptions`. I am not sure if the IME has an option itself to control this behavior, other than honoring `flagNoFullscreen` if/when it is applied.

Comment: Nice! Yeah I never would have guessed to look for something like that. Thanks for coming back despite me screwing up my image link :)